# What is the differentiation of $(1-x)^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

So how I am doing this is,

$$\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)^2
= 2(1-x)\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)
=2(1-x)(-1)
$$
But there isn't a minus sign in the actual answer. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong. Why do I have a minus in my answer?

Also I do realise, if $(1-x)^2$ is written as $(x-1)^2$ then there is no minus sign (assuming my solving technique is correct).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $2(1-x)(-1)=2(x-1)$. Check if the actual answer is $2(x-1)$.

Comment: $(x - 1) = -(1-x)$

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same result! If you apply the chain rule as you did, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1 - x)^{2} = 2(1 - x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1 - x) = 2(1 - x)(-1) = 2(x - 1) = 2x - 2
\end{align*}

Likewise, if we apply the chain rule to the other expression, one gets
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x - 1)^{2} = 2(x - 1)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x - 1) = 2x - 2
\end{align*}

which, as you can see, are both the same thing.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Aah okay. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnuragParasharSarmah Welcome to MSE! I am glad I could help.